# Zend application works on windows but not on Linux server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this problem, when I run my application developed with Zend Framework on a Linux server (Ubuntu or a hosted sever) the login won't work. The main problem is that the application can't write session on the server (I' set the directory where session should be written to 0777 ), in the other hand everything works perfect on my local WAMP server.

There's no exception, no error in the log file except this:

> PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

I'm stuck with this issue for two weeks now, please guide me.
Should I give the PHP files in Zend library any specific access right?

Comment: The warning displayed does not seem to be related to your issue, it is just telling you that safe_mode is running, but it is not throwing an error. The Linux/Windows issue often times comes down to capitalization, windows doesn't care and Linux does. Check your paths and filenames for proper and consistent caps and spelling.

Comment: @RockyFord Yes I did that in the first tests, I had this problem with some Files, now I checked them all.
I think the problem is related to access writing since the application on linux can't write sess_'Hash' on the server, but it's written in windows with no problem, the thing that I can't get why there's no error no exception ..

Comment: sometime i fogot create `sesson_save_dir` on server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed zend using CPanel, I don't know why but it's working now.